# exchange integral at large distances

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I want to ask a question about the exchange integral $\ce{H_{AB}}$ -

If I consider an exchange integral $\ce{H_{AB}}$ the following exchange integral can be evaluated:

[image]

so $\ce{S_{AB}}$ is $0$ at $\ce{R = \infty}$

but in this presentation I was shown today, at large values of R, $\ce{H_{AB}}$ is preportional to the overap integral $\ce{S_{AB}}$.

Surely at large distances and towards infinity, as $\ce{S_{AB}}$ goes to zero, $\ce{H_{AB}}$ also goes to zero too.

Where does the preportionality

$$H_{AB} \propto S_{AB}$$

come from then using these approimations when R is large?

Comment: Great question @vik1245. Would you be interested in committing to a brand new stack exchange dedicated towards computational modeling? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NzE1YTZmNTZhOGE1N2EwYWYzZGM2NWQyYTFiNzQ5ZDI5MWQyM2EwNzA5OWY5OWY2MDIzYzY2ZTMxNjJlYzIwMSLiKdOhPeuMkh2ODtejwcgH38HFpQq64gQljgKUrZrZ0. I wonder if you might be interested in committing to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the presentation is talking about large, but not yet very large/infinite distance here. Note the annotations:
$$
\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon R} = k/R
$$
when $R \rightarrow \infty$: **slowly** to zero

---

$$
S_{AB}
$$
when $R \rightarrow \infty$: to zero

---

$$
\left< 1s_A\left| k/r_A \right| 1s_B\right>
$$

when $R \rightarrow \infty$: **rapidly** to zero

---

So there is some regime somewhere, in which the change of the entire expression is dominated by the change in $S_{AB}$. The verification of the correctness of the different notations is apparently left to the reader ...